# UISearchController get searchScope index

Tags: ios, object, uisearchcontroller

`UISearchDisplayController` is deprecated in iOS 8 (`UISearchDisplayDelegate` is also deprecated.) So now i can't use next delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
```

I can use only `UISearchResultsUpdating` delegate method:

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
```

My question is how i can know when searchScore did change and which item is selected now if i have reference only to `UISearchController`. I was looking for a suitable property but did not find. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use UISearchBarDelegate

First, make sure your View Controller implement UISearchBarDelegate protocol like :

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {
//code
}
```

set the delegate :

```
controller.searchBar.delegate = self
```

then implement the following method :

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
    let scopeTitles = searchBar.scopeButtonTitles as [String]
    let scope = scopeTitles[selectedScope]
    println(scope)
}
```